# Error when validating iOS Apps in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I want to upload my app to the App Store but when I archive the Xcode project and first validate it until submit it I get this error:

[image]

I don't know why because I've got the Info.plist. Please can someone help me?

Comment: Is your plist listed under BuildSettings->Packaging->Info.plist File in your project file?

Comment: @AdamPro13 Yes but the message keeps appearing

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure then. The file names match, right?

Comment: @AdamPro13 Yes, well I have 2 Info.plist file, one is named Debug and the other one is named Release